# How to save object with relation using JAVA in Backendless 4.0?

Tags: java, android, database, backendless

> (SAVING DATA WITH RELATION USING BACKENDLESS 4.0)

I would like to save data with one to one relation.
example: -person_table have a relation with adress_table 
the data is save in person_table and address_table without relation. how can make this? #backendless4.0

```
Adress newAdress= new Adress();
    newAdress.setAdress("43 Street");
    newAdress.setPersonId(Person);
    Backendless.Persistence.save(newAdress, new AsyncCallback< Adress >() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(Adress response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
            fault.getMessage();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why the SHOUTING in the title

Comment: its a question , not an affirmation

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, verifiable, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have achieved and where the problems arise.

Comment: i saved the address but the pertsonId Relation is empty in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the result: 
for save with relation in backendless 4.0 you need to save the object first and save the relation after.

ref link 1 : [ADD RELATION WITH OBJECTS](https://backendless.com/docs/android/doc.html#data_add_relation_with_objects_android)
ref link 2 : [save object with relation using REST API](http://support.backendless.com/topic/backendless-4-0-save-object-with-relation-using-rest-api)

```
Person personObject = // personObject retrieval is out of scope in this example
        Adress objectAdress = // addressObject retrieval is out of scope in this example
        ArrayList< Person > personCollection = new ArrayList< Person >();
        personCollection.add( personObject );
        Backendless.Data.of( Adress.class ).addRelation( objectAdress, "personId:Adress:n", personCollection,
            new AsyncCallback<Integer>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse( Integer response )
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i( "MYAPP", "related objects have been added");
                }

                @Override
                public void handleFault( BackendlessFault fault )
                {

                }
            } );
```